# Flexbox with flow: column wrap and height: min-content not wrapping

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a tiny CSS problem. I have divs with different heights and would like the parent element to have the height of the biggest element and the rest of the elements to wrap accordingly. This works perfectly for rows (the parent element having the width of the widest element) with the code below, but for columns it doesn't work (just change the body class to column). Any idea how I could do this?

```css
body.row #parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap row;
  width: min-content;
}

body.row .child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: max-content;
}

body.column #parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap column;
  height: min-content;
}

body.column .child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: max-content;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body class="row">
  <div id='parent'>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
      <span>3. Line</span>
      <span>4. Line</span>
      <span>5. Line</span>
      <span>6. Line</span>
      <span>7. Line</span>
      <span>8. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-flex;` on `#parent`.

```css
body.row #parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap row;
  width: min-content;
}

body.row .child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: max-content;
}

body.column #parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: wrap column;
  height: min-content;
}

body.column .child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: max-content;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<body class="column">
  <div id='parent'>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
      <span>3. Line</span>
      <span>4. Line</span>
      <span>5. Line</span>
      <span>6. Line</span>
      <span>7. Line</span>
      <span>8. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I swear I tried that. But ommited it because it didn't seem to make a diffence.
Running this in Firefox 110 doesn't seem to wrap :(

Comment: @Tilman It's running for me in FF 110. Can you provide an image of the issue?

Comment: well they are just stacked vertically as if there was no wrap. Not sure what pages are ok (whitelisted) for hosting images for SO. Basically what you would get with only: flex-column

Answer (score 0):

`height: min-content;` is applied on all children collectively. If you want the children to wrap, you have to specify a `max-height: (somValue)px` on the `#parent`

```css
body.row #parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap row;
  width: min-content;
}

body.row .child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: max-content;
}

body.column #parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap column;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 200px
}

body.column .child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: max-content;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body class="column">
  <div id='parent'>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
      <span>3. Line</span>
      <span>4. Line</span>
      <span>5. Line</span>
      <span>6. Line</span>
      <span>7. Line</span>
      <span>8. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <span>1. Line</span>
      <span>2. Line</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But the amount of lines in the children is variable. I want the children to wrap with max-height being the height of heighest child.